# I am unable to create this regression with numpy and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Im trying to figure out what the next logical step is in order to create a linear regression for LeBron James' points per game for every season. I would like to make the X axis the seasons but I cant seem to get it to work properly. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong or point me towards a similar question that was already asked that would be great. Once I figure out how to do one for points per game I would like to then do the same thing for assists per game and maybe put them on the same graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.lines as mlines




data = pd.read_csv('lbj.csv')


data2 = data[['PTS','AST']] 
X1 = data[['Season']]
Y2 = str(data[['AST']])
Y1 = str(data[['PTS']])

plt.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'both', labelsize = 5)
plt.xticks(rotation = 50)


season = data.iloc[:,1]
points = data.iloc[:,-1]


np.polyfit(X1,Y1,1)
plt.show()
```

Any advice helps. Thank you.

```
print(data2.head())


0  20.9  5.9
1  27.2  7.2
2  31.4  6.6
3  27.3  6.0
4  30.0  7.2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for posting the code. Could you also post a code that we can copy/paste to create the DataFrame `data2` on our side. It could have first 5 to 10 rows from `lbj.csv`

Comment: I dont think I did that write but the middle column is 'PTS' and the column on the right is 'ASTS'

Answer (score 0):

1. Are Y1 and Y2, needed to be strings? Maybe the code below is enough.

**Update:** Since 'Season' data are strings, the X1 should be a range with length = number of seasons.

```
X1 = np.arange(data['Season'].size)
Y1 = data['PTS']
Y2 = data['AST']
```

See [this link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for full documentation of `np.arange`.

2. Regarding polyfit, it returns an array of polynomial coefficients. We can use poly1d to generate an "evaluator" for the polynomial.

```
Z = np.polyfit(X1, Y1, 1)
poly = np.poly1d(Z)
```

Of course, these functions have more functionalities than just this. See [this link](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) for full documentation of `np.polyfit`, and [this link](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) for `np.poly1d`.

3. For (basic) plotting, you can do this:

**Update:** 'Seasons' can directly be the X-axis.

```
seasons = data['Season']
plt.plot(seasons, Y1, 'blue')
plt.plot(seasons, poly(X1), 'red')
plt.show()
```

You can do the same for the AST.

Comment: I get a TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str for the polyfit function when I try this

Comment: @snay wait, what are you 'concatenating'? Take note that `data[['PTS']]` returns a different thing from `data['PTS']`. Also, I edited the plotting part (#3), because I made a mistake.

Comment: @snay Sorry for another question: are the "seasons" strings? My answer will fail to work if that is the case.

Comment: now for Z = np.polyfit(X1,Y1,1) I get the same error

Comment: oh yeah they are strings there are set up as '2003-2004' for example. I am sorry that I wasn't clear on that

Comment: Is there also a way to make the blue line a scatter chart instead?

Comment: `plt.plot(seasons, Y1, 'o', 'blue')` will do. The third argument specifies the 'shape' of plot.

Comment: can you explain the poly(X1) in the plt.plot(seasons, poly(X1), 'red')? Like what does that do? and can you give me a link to some documentation so I can read up on it?

Comment: @snay `np.poly1d` creates a class for the polynomial. See the examples [on this documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html).